# Neither 'ionic serve' nor 'npm run ionic:serve' are working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to run Ionic 3 application on the local host, at the beginning I was using the command

```
ionic serve
```

it was working, until it stopped suddenly and I did not know the reason, I searched for long time until I found an alternative command

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

It worked for a week then stopped, now I can't really figure out what to to do, I can't test any application, please help

here is the result of 'npm run ionic:serve'

```
> firstionicapp@0.0.1 ionic:serve C:\projects\ionic\firstionicapp
> ionic-app-scripts serve

[09:34:19]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.8
[09:34:19]  watch started ...
[09:34:19]  build dev started ...
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::53703
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
at new WebSocketServer (C:\projects\ionic\firstionicapp\node_modul\ws\lib\WebSocketServer.js:77:20)
at Object.createNotificationServer (C:\projects\ionic\firstionicapp  \node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\dev-server\notification-server.js:66:15)at C:\projects\ionic\firstionicapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\serve.js:47:31
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firstionicapp@0.0.1 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firstionicapp@0.0.1 ionic:serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Darkwood\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-24T07_34_19_839Z-debug.log
```

and here is the result of 'ionic serve'

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-    port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -
Ctrl+C to cancel
[09:43:24]  watch started ...
[09:43:24]  build dev started ...
```

here is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ionic:serve' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preionic:serve', 'ionic:serve', 'postionic:serve' ]
5 info lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~preionic:serve: ionic-basics@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: ionic-basics@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\projects\ionic\ionic-basics\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Darkwood\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Darkwood\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Users\Darkwood\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: CWD: C:\projects\ionic\ionic-basics
10 silly lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ionic-app-scripts serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ionic-basics@0.0.1~ionic:serve: Failed to exec ionic:serve script
13 verbose stack Error: ionic-basics@0.0.1 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid ionic-basics@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd C:\projects\ionic\ionic-basics
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ionic:serve"
18 verbose node v8.10.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ionic-basics@0.0.1 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ionic-basics@0.0.1 ionic:serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried every possible solution online, I tried even removing node.js and ionic and reinstalling them, but it did not work.
please help

Comment: you get an EADDRINUSE that means another app on your system is already using local port 53703.

Comment: when I saw this I tried restarting the computer but it did not help

Comment: try change the port

Comment: I have done this 
"ionic serve --port 100" for example but also did not work

Comment: should i clean the appdata/npm

Comment: it's the dev-logger-port

Comment: or change something in the system variables @evayly

Comment: sorry don't get you

Comment: --dev-logger-port 53703 
from your logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167459/discussion-between-armstring-and-evayly).

Answer (score 1):

Try running npm cache clean --force.
This should work, if it wont trying reinstalling node & do npm install again